# How to hide button in AngularJS when it have specific class on it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If i have a button like :

```
"<button class='btn btn-success dissabled' ng-show="">Next »</button>"
```

i want to hide it when there are a dissabled class on it, because it is done from some other Jquery library which i dont have control over.

Is it possible to be done inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do it with css:

```
.dissabled { display: none; }
```

If you need it to be specific to when you want:

```
.hide-if-dissabled.dissabled {
    display: none;
}
```

and then do

```
<button class='btn btn-success hide-if-dissabled dissabled'>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you can just

```
dissabled
{
  display:none;
}
```

ng-show and hide directives just add or remove a css class that changes the display.

Answer (score 0):

how about simply adding another class bound to the dissabled class to hide the element itself. Define it as such..

**CSS**

.dissabled.hide-when-dissabled {
  display: none !important;
}

**HTML** without `.dissabled` (This is the visible state of the element)

```
<button class='btn btn-success hide-when-dissabled' ng-show="">Next »</button>
```

**HTML** with `.dissabled` (This enables the css definition above, and hides the element)

```
<button class='btn btn-success hide-when-dissabled dissabled' ng-show="">Next »</button>
```